# Create folder in drive with rest v2 in android app

Tags: android, google-drive-api, directory, drive

I am trying to create a folder in Drive and using below

```
 String folderName = UrlConstants.APP_NAME + "_dont_delete";
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setTitle(folderName);
    fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

    File file = null;
    try {
        file = driveService.files().insert(fileMetadata)
                .setFields("id")
                .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However it is not creating folder in drive , instead it is creating a document named 'Untitled'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to get the value of folderName? Seems like you're not successfully getting the app_name. Let us know your findings.

Answer (score 1):

In [**Drive API for Android**](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders#top_of_page), note that working with folders has slight differences when compared to Google Drive API. Folders in the Drive API for Android are specialized resources within `metadata` and a `DriveId` and to create a folder, call `DriveFolder.createFolder` for the root folder. Then, pass the metadata containing the title and other attributes to set the values for the folder.

For a full working example, see the [CreateFolderActivity](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFolderActivity.java) sample in the [Google Drive Android API Demos app](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/).

Comment: Let me know if this helps

Comment: Please note i am using rest api not GDAA.

Answer (score 1):

The [CloudRail SDK](https://cloudrail.com/integrations/interfaces/CloudStorage;serviceIds=GoogleDrive;interfaceId=CloudStorage;interfaceFunctionId=CloudStorage-createFolder) allows you to do that in a pretty simple way:

```
GoogleDrive service = new GoogleDrive(
    this,
    "[Google Drive Client Identifier]",
    "[Google Drive Client Secret]",
    "http://localhost:12345/auth",
    "someState"
);

service.createFolder(
    "/myFolder"
);
```

Comment: Can you please provide tutorial link or complete doc reference to use drive in android for file CRUD operations.

Comment: You can find the full documentation here: https://cloudrail.com/integrations/interfaces/CloudStorage;serviceIds=GoogleDrive;interfaceId=CloudStorage;interfaceFunctionId=CloudStorage-createFolder